# Scala broadcast join with "one to many" relationship

Tags: scala, join, broadcast

I am fairly new to Scala and RDDs.
I have a very simple scenario yet it seems very hard to implement with RDDs.

Scenario:
I have two tables. One large and one small. I broadcast the smaller table.
I then want to join the table and finally aggregate the values after the join to a final total.

Here is an example of the code:

```
val bigRDD = sc.parallelize(List(("A",1,"1Jan2000"),("B",2,"1Jan2000"),("C",3,"1Jan2000"),("D",3,"1Jan2000"),("E",3,"1Jan2000")))
val smallRDD = sc.parallelize(List(("A","Fruit","Apples"),("A","ZipCode","1234"),("B","Fruit","Apples"),("B","ZipCode","456")))

val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(smallRDD.keyBy{ a => (a._1,a._2) }  // turn to pair RDD
  .collectAsMap()               // collect as Map
)

//first join
val joinedRDD = bigRDD.map( accs => {
  //get list of groups
  val groups = List("Fruit", "ZipCode")
  val i = "Fruit"
  //for each group
  //for(i <- groups) {
  if (broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1, i) != None) {
    ( broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1, i).get._1,
      broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1, i).get._2,
      accs._2, accs._3)
  } else {
    None
  }
  //}
}
)
//expected after this
//("A","Fruit","Apples",1, "1Jan2000"),("B","Fruit","Apples",2, "1Jan2000"),
//("A","ZipCode","1234", 1,"1Jan2000"),("B","ZipCode","456", 2,"1Jan2000")

//then group and sum
//cannot do anything with the joinedRDD!!!
//error == value copy is not a member of Product with Serializable

// Final Expected Result
//("Fruit","Apples",3, "1Jan2000"),("ZipCode","1234", 1,"1Jan2000"),("ZipCode","456", 2,"1Jan2000")
```

My questions:

- Is this the best approach first of all with RDDs? 
  Disclaimer - I have done this whole task using dataframes successfully. The idea is to create another version using only RDDs to compare performance.
- Why is the type of my joinedRDD not recognised after it was created so that I can continue to use functions like copy on it?
- How can I get away with not doing a .collectAsMap() when broadcasting the variable. I currently have to include the first to items to enforce uniqueness and not dropping any values.

Thanks for the help in advance!

---

### **Final solution for anyone interested**

```
case class dt (group:String, group_key:String, count:Long, date:String)

val bigRDD = sc.parallelize(List(("A",1,"1Jan2000"),("B",2,"1Jan2000"),("C",3,"1Jan2000"),("D",3,"1Jan2000"),("E",3,"1Jan2000")))
val smallRDD = sc.parallelize(List(("A","Fruit","Apples"),("A","ZipCode","1234"),("B","Fruit","Apples"),("B","ZipCode","456")))

val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(smallRDD.keyBy{ a => (a._1) }  // turn to pair RDD
    .groupByKey()                 //to not loose any data
    .collectAsMap()               // collect as Map
)

//first join
val joinedRDD = bigRDD.flatMap( accs => {
  if (broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1) != None) {
  val bc = broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1).get
    bc.map(p => {
      dt(p._2, p._3,accs._2, accs._3)
    })
  } else {
    None
  }
}
)
//expected after this
//("Fruit","Apples",1, "1Jan2000"),("Fruit","Apples",2, "1Jan2000"),
//("ZipCode","1234", 1,"1Jan2000"),("ZipCode","456", 2,"1Jan2000")

//then group and sum
var finalRDD = joinedRDD.map(s => {
  (s.copy(count=0),s.count)  //trick to keep code to minimum (count = 0)
  })
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map(pair => {
    pair._1.copy(count=pair._2)
  })
```

Comment: is broadcasting mandatory?

Comment: for performance, unfortunately yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your map statement you return either a tuple or None based on the if condition.  These types do not match so you fall back the a common supertype so `joinedRDD` is an `RDD[Product with Serializable]` Which is not what you want at all (it's basically `RDD[Any]`).  You need to make sure all paths return the same type.  In this case, you probably want an `Option[(String, String, Int, String)]`.  All you need to do is wrap the tuple result into a `Some`

```
  if (broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1, i) != None) {
    Some(( broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1, i).get.group_key,
      broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1, i).get.group,
      accs._2, accs._3))
  } else {
    None
  }
```

And now your types will match up.  This will make `joinedRDD` and `RDD[Option(String, String, Int, String)]`.  Now that the type is correct the data is usable, however, it means that you will need to map the Option to work with the tuples.  If you don't need the `None` values in the final result, you can use `flatmap` instead of `map` to create `joinedRDD` which will unwrap the Options for you, filtering out all the `None`s.

`CollectAsMap` is the correct way to turnan RDD into a Hashmap, but you need multiple values for a single key.  Before using `collectAsMap` but after mapping the smallRDD into a Key,Value pair, use `groupByKey` to group all of the values for a single key together.  When when you look up a key from your HashMap, you can map over the values, creating a new record for each one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and clear reply!! 
I have been trying to implement your seconds suggestion with the keys as well. Quick question, can you use a for loop within the map function?

   `val joinedRDD = bigRDD.map( accs => {
      if (broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1) != None) {
        **for(i <- broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1).get) { **
          Some(i._1, i._2, i._3, accs._2, accs._3)
        }
      } else {
        None
      }
    }
    )`

Comment: No worries - I have managed to find the solution... thanks for your help today @puhlen!!
val joinedRDD = bigRDD.flatMap( accs => {
      if (broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1) != None) {
      val bc = broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1).get
        bc.map(p => {
          dt(p._2, p._3,accs._2, accs._3)
        })
      } else {
        None
      }
    }
    )

Comment: @Estee note that you can replace the if check by simply using map.  `bigRDD.flatMap( accs => broadcastVar.value.get(accs._1).map(_.map(p => dt(p._2, p._3,accs._2, accs._3)) )`